# How can I remove spacing around a widget in a layout?

Tags: qt, layout

I am trying to insert a very tiny `QLabel` into a very tiny `QFrame`.

The `QFrame` is used as a spacer and I thought it a perfect place to add text.

In code that text would change (`in` to `mm`). Because `mm` is so *giant* it is clipped...

Yet it seems to me it would fit if I could just get rid of the margins !

[image]

So I try:

`ui->tinyFrame` is created in Designer... it has geometry 0,0,10,10

```
QLabel* unitLabel  = new QLabel("mm");
unitLabel->setFixedSize(8,8);
unitLabel->setFont(QFont("Arial Narrow", 7));
unitLabel->setMargin(0);
unitLabel->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

QHBoxLayout* unitLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
unitLayout->setSpacing(0);    // I try everything
unitLayout->setMargin(0);
unitLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
ui->tinyFrame->setLayout(unitLayout);
ui->tinyFrame->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
unitLayout->addWidget(unitLabel);
```

What else can I try to remove the space around my little label ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to insert a very tiny QLabel into a very tiny QFrame.
>   What can I try to remove the space around my little label?

`QLabel` is derived from `QFrame`: maybe you can just replace that `QFrame` with `QLabel` then? And no nested layout for that frame.

... as long as you tried `layout->setSpacing(0)` already...

Comment: I tried - the text is still clipped. But for some reason the left margin disappeared. I ended up just giving it a bigger size - and the size didn't increase, the text was not clipped anymore... I don't understand but it worked